# Select multiple items using react hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

I am building a next js application. Here I am creating a custom dropdown select menu. using react hook-- `useState`.. I write the code following way.

Data-

```
export default [
    { name: "Xioami" },
    { name: "Samsung" },
    { name: "Apple" },
    { name: "Oppo" },
    { name: "Techno" },
    { name: "Itel" },
    { name: "Oneplus" },
    { name: "Amazon" },
    { name: "Okla" },
    { name: "Chemisty" },
    { name: "Physics" },
]
```

React Component-

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { List, ListItem, ButtonBase, Typography } from "@mui/material";

//Styles
import useStyles from "Styles/Category/FilterWidget.styles";

//Data
import BrandData from "Data/Header/Brand.Data";

const Brand = ({ setFilterData }) => {
    const [brands, setBreands] = useState(null);
    const classes = useStyles();
    return (
        <div>
            <List className={classes.List}>
                {BrandData &&
                    BrandData.map((brand, i) => (
                        <ListItem key={i}>
                            <ButtonBase
                                onClick={() => setBreands(brand.name)}
                                className={brands === brand.name ? "selected" : ""}
                            >
                                <Typography variant="body1" component="p">
                                    {brand.name}
                                </Typography>
                            </ButtonBase>
                        </ListItem>
                    ))
                }
            </List>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Brand;
```

In the component, I add `onClick` and `className` as well. When user click an item, it store in `useState` and then when matched name, it also add a `selected` class.

But problem is that at a time user can select just one item. But I need the functionality to add multiple item into `useState` and then add a `className` to that item. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store an array or `Set` of selected items, not just a single selected item.

For example (see comments):

```
const Brand = ({ setFilterData }) => {
    // *** Default state is an empty set vvvvvvvvv
    const [brands, setBrands] = useState(new Set());
    const classes = useStyles();

    // Select a brand
    const selectBrand = (brand) => {
        // *** Use the callback version here, since you're setting state
        // based on existing state
        setBrands(brands => {
            if (!brands.has(brand)) {
                brands = new Set(brands);
                brands.add(brand);
            }
            // *** You might have an `else` here calling
            // `delete` if you want clicks to toggle
            // selection
            return brands;
        });
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <List className={classes.List}>
                {BrandData &&
                    BrandData.map((brand, i) => (
                        <ListItem key={i}>
                            <ButtonBase
                                {/* *** Click selects the brand */}
                                onClick={() => selectBrand(brand)}
                                {/* *** Test that the brand is selected via `has` */}
                                className={brands.has(brand) ? "selected" : ""}
                            >
                                <Typography variant="body1" component="p">
                                    {brand.name}
                                </Typography>
                            </ButtonBase>
                        </ListItem>
                    ))
                }
            </List>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Comment: Thank you. I am trying it..